# Why does the location of my vehicle spawner change when I open a matinee?

Tags: unreal, map-editor

I'm doing work with InterActors and vehicle spawners in Unreal Tournament 3's editor, and have it set up like so:

[image: Image1]

(The Walkway its on is the InterActor)

However if I go in Kemsit and open the matinee that handles the InterActor, this happens:

[image]

It does look to me like the editor is moving it out of the way so I can see the InterActor (which would be very clever) because only the image of the vehicle moves, not the gizmo, nor does the vehicle spawn in that location in game.

Is this the case?